# Is O(3^n) still written as O(2^n)?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, computer-science, exponential

I'm wondering if an algorithm with an exponential worst time complexity, should always have that stated as O(2^n). For example, if I had an algorithm that's operations triple for each addition to the input size, would I write it's time complexity as O(3^n), or would it still be classified as O(2^n).

Any formal explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `3^n` is the same as `2^(log3 * n)`. So `3^n` is the same complexity as `2^m` where `m=log3*n`.

Comment: Go back to the definition: is there a constant `C` such that `3^n <= C*2^n` for all sufficiently large `n`?  Drawing a graph of `3^n / 2^n` should suggest the answer pretty clearly, and a mathematical proof is not much harder.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
3^n != O(2^n).
```

Let us assume that it were true.
Then there exists constants `c` and `n0` such that `3^n ≤ c * 2^n` for all `n ≥ n0`.

The last requirement is equivalent to `(3/2)^n ≤ c` for all `n ≥ n0`.

However, `(3/2)^n → ∞` as `n → ∞`, so `(3/2)^n ≤ c` cannot be true for all `n ≥ n0` for any constant `c`.

Answer (score 2):

No, O(2^n) and O(3^n) are different. If 3^n were O(2^n), there'd be a constant k such that 3^n <= k * 2^n for all large n. There's no such k because 3^n / 2^n is (3/2)^n which grows arbitrarily large.